# attach functions to DOM objects using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'd like to attach functions to existing DOM element in a web page. Is there a way to use jQuery selectors to create a set of DOM elements and append a function to them?

I'm doing it in javascript now like so:

```
    var domObject;
    domObject = document.getElementById('WeatherObservation.Temperature');
    if (domObject) {
        domObject.format = function (val) {
            var fTemp = val * 9 / 5 + 32;
            var fDisp = Math.round((fTemp + Number.EPSILON) * 10) / 10;
            this.innerText = fDisp.toString();
        }
    };
```

Comment: Yes, via the jQuery `.each()` method, though it won't be much different than using browser APIs. It definitely will not attach the function to a list of elements for you.

Comment: If `this.innerText` is all your need for `this`, then it might as well be an argument to the function: `const writeFormattedValueToElement = (element, value) => { /* ... */ }`. Or, better yet, `for (const element of elements) { element.innerText = format(value); }`.

Comment: @InSync making the property to update an argument assumes the caller knows which property to update. In my case it doesn't. I'm hiding the details of presentation.

Comment: @jabaa It's a function to convert from Celsius to Fahrenheit and update the DOM element

Answer (score 3):

You can use `.data()` to associate a named value with all the selected elements, and this value can be a function.

To refer to the element itself, make this function a closure that captures the element that it was attached to.

```
$(".classname").each(function(i, element) {
  $(element).data("format", function(val) {
    var fTemp = val * 9 / 5 + 32;
    var fDisp = Math.round((fTemp + Number.EPSILON) * 10) / 10;
    element.innerText = fDisp.toString();
  });
});
```

You can later call the function with `$("selector").data("format")(someVal)`

Comment: Almost works: Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: this is undefined
    onload index.js:60
    <anonymous> index.js:91

Comment: I didn't notice that you were trying to refer to the element itself in the function. So it will need to be a closure. I'll update the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can set a custom method using the [`.data()`](https://api.jquery.com/data) method.

**Example:**

```js
$('.myClass').data({
  'format': (function() {
    var fTemp = val * 9 / 5 + 32;
    var fDisp = Math.round((fTemp + Number.EPSILON) * 10) / 10;
    this.innerText = fDisp.toString();
  })
});

// Call this later:

$(mySelector).data('format')(...arguments);
```

Or, you can set a custom **event** using the [`.trigger()`](https://api.jquery.com/trigger) method. Note that events cannot return a value, so don't use this approach if you need to return a value.

**Example:**

```js
$('.myClass').trigger({
  'format': (function() {
    var fTemp = val * 9 / 5 + 32;
    var fDisp = Math.round((fTemp + Number.EPSILON) * 10) / 10;
    this.innerText = fDisp.toString();
  })
});

// Trigger the event:

$(mySelector).trigger('format');
```

Comment: There's no need for `.each()`. The `.text()` method can take a function.

Comment: This isn't associating a function with each element, it's setting its text.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot the OP asked about appending the function. Edited after re-reading the question.

Comment: You're calling the function and attaching its return value, not attaching the function.

Comment: `this.data` should be `$(this).data`

Comment: `.data()` automatically loops over a collection, there's no need for `.each()`